# Python cross compilation for arm cortex A8

Tags: python, arm, cross-compiling

I am having a problem with cross compiling Python using Code Sourcery toolchain:

```
./configure -host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi CC=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc RANLIB=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ranlib STRIP=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-strip --build=arm-none-linux --disable-ipv6 ac_cv_file__dev_ptmx=no ac_cv_file__dev_ptc=no ac_cv_have_long_long_format=yes

make CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi- CROSS_COMPILE_TARGET=yes

make install CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi- CROSS_COMPILE_TARGET=yes prefix=~/Python-2.7.2/_install
```

Make command finishes successfully with following warning:

> Python build finished, but the necessary bits to build these modules
>   were not found:
>   _bsddb _curses _curses_panel 
>   _sqlite3 _ssl _tkinter  bsddb185 bz2 dbm  dl gdbm imageop  linuxaudiodev ossaudiodev readline  sunaudiodev zlib

It seems like Python has been compiled for target machine, it can be run on it but I cannot start desired program, it finishes with following errors:

> root@dm814x-evm:~/nfs-share/opbasm# **python opbasm.py meas_ctrl.hex** 
>   Traceback (most recent call last): File "opbasm.py", line 32, in
>    import subprocess File
>   "/home/root/Python/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 72, in 
>   import select ImportError: No module named select

Could you help me find a solution for successful cross compilation Python on Arm cortex A8?

Best regards,

Jacob

Comment: Have you tried setting the PYTHONPATH to wherever your `python2.7/site-packages` is stored on target board?

Comment: Yes, but that directory is empty.